# Change display language at runtime and recreate all activities

Tags: android, android-activity, multilingual

I want to be able to change the display language in my Android application at runtime without the need to restart the app. To do this I believe it is possible to recreate all of the running activities. The problem is I don't have any idea how to get a reference to all activities that haven't been destroyed by the `ActivityManager`.

Comment: You mean, changing the language of the app, without going to device settings? Can you elaborate, what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: You may write something in the `onResume()` method to check if the language setting has changed, and if so, update all the visuals elements that contain locale strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "locale" property in your android:configChanges in all you activities and then override onConfigurationChanged() in activities and handle the language changes accordingly.

More on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Answer (score 2):

This approach will work on all `API` level device, make sure to recreate activity on changing language programmatically.

1.Use `BaseActivity` for `attachBaseContext` to set the locale language and `extends` this `Activity` for all activities

```
open class  BaseAppCompactActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(newBase))

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

}
```

2. Use Application `attachBaseContext` and `onConfigurationChanged` to set the locale language

   ```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {

      private static MyApplication application;

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
       }

       public static MyApplication getApplication() {
           return application;
       }

       /**
        * overide to change local sothat language can be chnaged from android device  nogaut and above
        */
       @Override
       protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
           super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.INSTANCE.onAttach(base));
       }

       @Override
       public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
       /*** also handle chnage  language if  device language chnaged **/

           super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

       }
   ```
3. Use Locale `Helper` for handling language changes ,this approach work on all device

   ```
    object LocaleHelper {


   fun onAttach(context: Context, defaultLanguage: String): Context {
       return setLocale(context, defaultLanguage)
   }



   fun setLocale(context: Context, language: String): Context {
       return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
           updateResources(context, language)
       } else updateResourcesLegacy(context, language)

   }


   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
   private fun updateResources(context: Context, language: String): Context {
       val locale = Locale(language)
       Locale.setDefault(locale)

       val configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration()
       configuration.setLocale(locale)
       configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)

       return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
   }

   private fun updateResourcesLegacy(context: Context, language: String): Context {
       val locale = Locale(language)
       Locale.setDefault(locale)

       val resources = context.getResources()

       val configuration = resources.getConfiguration()
       configuration.locale = locale
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
           configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale)
       }
       resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics())
       return context
     }
   }
   ```